# helm templating with toYaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have values.yml file that takes in a list of ports with this format and default values:

```
Ports:
  - number: 443
    protocol: http
```

The script that output the list of port to use as my input gives me this format:

`port_list=$(./get_ports.sh)`

output:

```
- 80
- 8080
```

I want the resulting rendered template to be

```
Ports:
  - number: 80
  - number: 8080
```

How would I accomplish this? I tried the following in my template file:

```
{{- with .Values.Ports }}
Ports:
  {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
{{- end }}
```

using helm template and setting `values.Ports=$port_list`, it ended up giving me a pipe and an extra dash like below, which I do not know where they come from, how do I accomplish getting to the format I want above based on the input?

```
Ports:
|-
  - number: 80
  - number: 8080
```

As a bonus, I would also like to have a default protocol in my port list when the protocol isn't specified.

```
Ports:
  - number: 80
    protocol: http
  - number: 8080
    protocol: http
```

Is there a clean way to do this with just templating?

Comment: can your get_ports.sh output in other format? for example `a, b, c`

Comment: try removing `-` from  `{{- toYaml . [...]`, and also try using `indent` instead of `nindent`

Comment: I know I'm a bit late here, but I strongly recommend _against_ using `toYaml` because it means you suddenly have to care about indentation.  Given that YAML is a superset of JSON, it's probably better to just use `Ports: {{ toJson . }}` instead.  You will get the desired result without having to worry about whitespace or formatting issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mr.Llama , it works  now with {{ toJson  .}} as you said I will get the desired result without having to worry about whitespace or formatting issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you have to know about the YAML syntax about string. You can find it by searching on the internet. For example: see [YAML Multiline](https://yaml-multiline.info/).

`|` enables multiline string and `-` chops the trailing `\n` from the end of the string.

The reason for appearing `|-` is the output of the script `get_ports.sh` (is being treated as a single string). You can test this,

```sh
port_list=$(get_ports.sh)
# pass this to the `--set` flag in both of the following ways
# 01: pass the var $port_list
--set ports=$port_list
# 02: directly pass the value of the var $port_list
--set ports="- 80
- 8080"
```

For both of the tests you have the same output as follows:

```
ports:
|-
  - 80
  - 8080
```

If you put a newline at the end of the output of your script, then you will see the `-` has disappeared.

```sh
--set ports="- 80
- 8080
"
```

The output is like as following:

```
ports:
|
  - 80
  - 8080
```

Now try in a different way. Change your template to like this one:

```
{{- if .Values.ports }}
  {{- print "ports:" | nindent 2 }}
  {{- range $_, $p := .Values.ports }}
    - number: {{ $p }}
      protocol: http
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

This template expects the value of your ports in the `--set` flag as a list (not a string). According to my knowledge at the time of writing this answer, to provide a list value in `--set` flag either of the followings can be used:

- `--set ports={80\,8080}`
- `--set ports[0]=80,ports[1]=8080`

Now the output is same as you want.

```sh
$ helm template test . --set ports={80\,8080}
ports:
  - number: 80
    protocol: http
  - number: 8080
    protocol: http
```

So all you need to process the output of `get_ports.sh`. That's it.

> **You may need to adjust the indentation in the template**