# Helm configmap error. expected string; got bool

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a Helm chart with has multiple templates. One is the configmap which was working fine.
But when I want to add the enabled part I´m getting the error message.

```
executing "base-helm-chart/templates/configmap.yaml" at <$config>: wrong type for value; expected string; got bool
```

This are the files I´m using:

```
{{- if .Values.configMap.enabled }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  name: {{include "chart.fullname" .}}
  labels: {{ include "chart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
data:
{{- range $name, $config := .Values.configMap }}
  {{ $name }}: |
{{ tpl $config $ | indent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end -}}
```

values.yaml

```
configMap:
  enabled: true
  config.json: |
    food = pizza
    drink = soda
```

I want user to enable/disable if he wants to add configmap or not from the values.yaml

Comment: [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) function expects string and you are providing bool that the cause of the error

Comment: but the values passed are string. The boolean value is just to set the enable/disable flag. How can it be modified?

Comment: while looping over `Values.configMap` you are accessing `enabled` and `config.json`, enabled is boolean which is getting passed to `tpl` which is causing the issue you can either add condition to ignore or use `config.json` directly.

Comment: how would you add a condition to ignore? I think that´s why I need

Comment: please check the example in the answer and let me know if I missed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add condition to skip value of another type then string to be passed in [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) function

```golang
{{- range $name, $config := .Values.configMap -}}
{{ if typeOf $config | eq "string" }}
{{ $name }}: |
{{- tpl $config $ | nindent 12 }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

If you want to also print another key value in output then you can use `print`, `printf`, `println` or any other print option.

```golang
{{- range $name, $config := .Values.configMap -}}
{{ if typeOf $config | eq "string" }}
{{ $name }}: |
{{- tpl $config $ | nindent 12 }}
{{- else -}}
{{ printf "%v: %v" $name $config }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want user to enable/disable if he wants to add configmap or not from the values.yaml

Does this mean that *by default* the `configMap` is empty?
If that's the case, you can check for the empty value

```
{{- if .Values.configMap }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  name: {{include "chart.fullname" .}}
  labels: {{ include "chart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
data:
{{- range $name, $config := .Values.configMap }}
  {{ $name }}: |
{{ tpl $config $ | indent 4 }}
  {{- end }}

{{- end -}}
```

and in `values.yaml` the default is an empty dictionary:

```yaml
configMap: {}
```

In this way, only when a user fills in `configMap`, the manifest will be generated.

Aside from this optional activation, you seem to have a problem in the iteration over the values, because they differ types.

You can use the much simpler `toYaml` filter (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62307183/helm-templating-with-toyaml))

The end result could be something like this:

```
{{- if .Values.configMap }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  name: {{include "chart.fullname" .}}
  labels: {{ include "chart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
data:
{{- toYaml .Values.configMap | nindent 2 -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: By default  it´s enabled: true and some default values . I know that the option exist. to enable or desable. With ingress for example. You can put enabled : true/false. Want the same but with config map. As I said same code works if I just put:  {{- if .Values.configMap }} but I want to add the .enabled and user to set either to true or false in values.yaml and have the chance to add values that they want to be pass into Configmap.yaml below  "data:"

Comment: The second snippet can be extended: if you have a subsection `configMap.data` to hold the user-data and an `enabled` bool, you can use `{{- if .Values.configMap.enabled }}` on top