# Include and toyaml can render the same template in the helm. Which should I use?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

`include` and `toyaml` have the same function.
which one is recommended?

my helm version

```bash
$ helm version --short
v3.12.0+gc9f554d
```

### `include`

deployment.yaml

```yaml
        {{- include "template.resources" . | nindent 8 }}
```

_helpers.tpl

```yaml
{{/*
resources
*/}}
{{- define "template.resources" -}}
resources:
  limits:
    memory: {{ .Values.resources.limits.memory}}
    cpu: {{ .Values.resources.limits.cpu}}
  requests:
    memory: {{ .Values.resources.requests.memory}}
    cpu: {{ .Values.resources.requests.memory}}  
{{- end }}
```

values.yaml

```yaml
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 512Mi
    cpu: "1"
  requests:
    memory: 256Mi
    cpu: "0.2"
```

### `toyaml`

deployment.yaml

```yaml
        resources:
          {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 10 }}
```

values.yaml

```yaml
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 512Mi
    cpu: "1"
  requests:
    memory: 256Mi
    cpu: "0.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

**include:**
makes it possible to include a template, and then perform an operation on that template's output, Helm has a special include function ([see official helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-include-function)).

**toYaml:**
toYaml can be used to copy chunks of yaml from any source ([see offical helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/)).

**For example**, you can escape dot sequences, which may come in handy when charts use the toYaml function to parse annotations, labels and node selectors.

The syntax for `--set nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/role"=master` becomes:

```
nodeSelector:
  kubernetes.io/role: master
```

[relate topic: "helm templating with toYaml"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62307183/helm-templating-with-toyaml)